# Can't Load Models for face-api.js despite infereing the models

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, face-api

I'm trying to make the app for face detection. But despite loading models. I'm getting the error **"SsdMobilenetv1 - load model before inference"**
I'm sending the Front End HTML File from the server. and on the client front end I'm trying to do the face detection. I would be very very grateful for your kind response. Regards!!!

This is my express server

Index.js

```
const express = require("express")
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const hbs = require("hbs")


const publicFolder = path.join(__dirname, '../public')
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, "../views")

app.use(express.static(publicFolder));


app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.set("views", viewsPath);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.hbs')
})

app.listen(7000, () => {
    console.log("Listening On port")
})
```

This is the script file on front end face.js

```
const MODEL_URL = "/weights";
Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL),
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL),
    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL),
]).then((val) => {
    // console here gives an array of undefined
    console.log(val)
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})

const img = document.getElementById('img')
const inputField = document.getElementById('imgUpload')
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')

const inputChangeListner = function (e) {
    var selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    img.title = selectedFile.name;

    reader.onload = function (event) {
        console.log(event)
        img.src = event.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
}
inputField.onchange = inputChangeListner


faceapi.detectSingleFace(img).then((value) => {
 console.log(value)
}).catch((err) => { console.log(err) })
```

Because of low reputation, i can't post the image directly but  here is the link to my folder structure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xswbl.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that only two parts in your client-side script are relevant for this issue, so let's focus on those:

```
const MODEL_URL = "/weights";
Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL),
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL),
    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL),
]).then((val) => {
    // console here gives an array of undefined
    console.log(val)
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})

// ...

faceapi.detectSingleFace(img).then((value) => {
 console.log(value)
}).catch((err) => { console.log(err) })
```

so, we've got a `Promise.all` at the top which schedules execution of 3 functions, `ssdMobilenetv1` among them, which [is obligatory](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/#loading-the-models) to call prior to calling `faceapi.detectSingleFace`. But, the problem is, these 3 functions from within `Promise.all` will be executed asynchronously, while main thread will go forward and try to invoke `faceapi.detectSingleFace`, even though `ssdMobilenetv1` is still going on.

Simplest solution would be to put `detectSingleFace` to the success callback of `Promise.all`:

```
const MODEL_URL = "/weights";
Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL),
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL),
    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL),
]).then((val) => {
    // console here gives an array of undefined
    console.log(val);
    faceapi.detectSingleFace(img).then((value) => {
     console.log(value)
    }).catch((err) => { console.log(err) });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
});
```

Because inside the callback, you can be sure that `faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1` is done.

Comment: It worked!!! I'm grateful. It should have been obvious that because of the asynchronous nature. detectSingleFace was running before loading the SsdMobilenetv1. Really appreciate your help