# detectAllFaces() method can not recognize any faces in face-api.js

Tags: javascript, python, keras, face-detection, face-api

I'm using [face-api.js](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js) Javascript API to develop a web app that user uploads her/his picture and we want to detect faces in the picture.

this is my HTML codes:

```
<input type="file" id="user_pic" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">
<img src="images/250x250.webp" id="preview" alt="">
```

and following code are what I wrote to face detection:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    run()
});

async function run() {
    // load the models
    await faceapi.loadMtcnnModel('../faceapi_models')
    await faceapi.loadFaceRecognitionModel('../faceapi_models')
}


const user_pic = document.getElementById('user_pic')
const preview = document.getElementById('preview')

user_pic.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        preview.src = e.target.result
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(user_pic.files[0]);

    detectFaces(user_pic.files[0])
})

preview.onclick = () => user_pic.click()


async function detectFaces(input) {

    let imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(input)

    const imgElement = new Image()
    imgElement.src = imgURL

    const results = faceapi.detectAllFaces(imgElement)
        .withFaceLandmarks()
        .withFaceExpressions()
    console.log(results)

    results.forEach(result => {
        const { x, y, width, height } = result.detection.box;
        ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
    });

}
```

Now whenever I select an image `results` variable is empty and this error occured:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: results.forEach is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `withFaceExpressions()` method is `async`. You should use `await` or `then()`.

[Documentation for the reference](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js)

Using **await**

```js
const results = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(imgElement)
   .withFaceLandmarks()
   .withFaceExpressions();
```

Using **then()**

```js
faceapi.detectAllFaces(imgElement)
   .withFaceLandmarks()
   .withFaceExpressions()
   .then( results => {
      results.forEach(result => {
        const { x, y, width, height } = result.detection.box;
        ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
      });
   });
```

Comment: that error is solved but now I got this error : `Uncaught (in promise) Error: SsdMobilenetv1 - load model before inference`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565669/cant-load-models-for-face-api-js-despite-infereing-the-models

Comment: Thanks @BadPiggie, But now I got another erorr : `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d is not a function`